# Replace text of a URLwith Python

Tags: python, pandas, url

How can i replace the text of a URL for another? Like this

CODE:

```
current_url = dfurl.replace("v01", "depot")
print(current_url)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLFkU.png)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You have the code you need to replace text within a string. Is there another issue?

Comment: in the image below doesnt chage the url text, 'v01' to 'depot'

Comment: this is the url:  http://windte1909.acepta.com/v01/2DD56893C4E2DA0B6EF4D615EF54CD6587A2C247

Comment: what's the type of dfurl? you might need to just cast as a string. ```current_url = str(dfurl).replace(...)```

Comment: okay I moved my comment to an actual answer, since that was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dfurl is apparently an object and not a string, so you just need to cast it like so

```py
current_url = str(dfurl).replace("v01", "depot")
```